# Visual Studio 2017 - Toolbox not loaded and hanging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed Visual Studio 2017 in my Windows 10.

I got error in initializing the Toolbox and it keep hanging.

Is there something I can do with?

I have launched the VS 2017 with Administrator, but this doesn't resolved the issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you check VS2017 Support center? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24723/visual-studio-freezes-when-i-open-the-toolbox.html

Comment: I removed Xamarin and it works! but i will try again to install Xamarin and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled Azure stuff and Clang/C2 and Toolset for Visual 2015.3 v140 and Xamarin stuff and added Apache Ant. After that it worked. So some of the above seams to resolve the issue. I will not do further investigation, because for me it is OK without that stuff.

Comment: I think Xamarin is causing the issue. After removing it, the toolbox starts to work well!

Comment: Don't need to remove just disable them.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I did have Xamarin installed but not Android SDK, because I had it already installed for various other tools.

Turns out this is caused by Xamarin trying to access Android SDK, which isnt there. Solution seems to be to either  **remove Xamarin** or **install Android SDK**, according to [development community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24723/visual-studio-freezes-when-i-open-the-toolbox.html).

Unfortunatly, installing Xamarin and going into Xamarin/Android Settings to point to existing Android SDK (without it) also seems to hang VS2017.

**HOWEVER...**

If you want to keep Xamarin and use your own Android SDK/NDK, what you can do is:

1. Lauch Visual Studio 2017 Installer
2. Install Xamarin and Android SDK (dont need to install NDK as well)
3. Launch Visual Studio 2017
4. Go into Tools / Options / Xamarin / Android Settings (It wont hang
   now)
5. Point to your existing Andoid SDK / NDK and Java runtime you want to
   use
6. Close VS2017
7. Go back to Visual Studio Installer
8. Uninstall Android SDK

Before that I tried to define an `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable and tried to set the paths in registry, neither of those helped. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Good information provided. I will try this if I'm facing this issue again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the voodoo solutions, removed every extension (xamarin included) and every package except the core .net and C# VS, which I updated to the latest version available v15.9.30.  Same problem.

The solution for me was to uninstall an office plugin/tool from a previous visual studio.

The problem app was "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools For Office Runtime (x64)".  After I uninstalled it, the problem was gone.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Please consider to remove the part where you describe things that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by simple solution.
Follow these steps:

1. Run VS, continue without code
2. Menu View/Toolbox to show Tollbox
3. Close VS and run again
4. Open or create your project